# How to make kde remember printing options?

Tags: printing, kde-4

All kde applications use the same print widget. But every time i want to print something - I have to set options: grayscale, duplex, two pages per sheet, with single line border.

Is there any way to make kde remember those options, and use them always?

Comment: Maybe this feature "died" with KDE 3.5?!?

Comment: It's possible. A lot of good stuff from kde 3.5 does not exist in kde4 :(

Answer (score 0):

Which distribution? In case of Kubuntu simply use the Printer Configuration applet. There you can set global settings.

Comment: Went to printer configuration. chose my printer, in options, have double sided printing enabled, but nothing about printing >1 page per page of output. in normal print dialog, i still have duplex disabled (can enable, on each print separately), and i can set >1 page per page of print.